# Can I import the whole firebase file?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, visual-studio-code, import

I was making a linkedin clone following Clever programmer's video. In their video they Imported firebase using `import firebase from "firebase"`

But I can't import firebase from firebase. I can only import folders in firebase eg: auth, app

Also I have the Import cost extension installed. It detects firebase/auth, firebase/firestore
kind of imports but it doesn't detect `import firebase from firebase`

How can I solve this problem. Any help will be much appreciated. I'm stuck for 5 days now.

Comment: "I can't import firebase from firebase" Why not? What is keeping you from doing this? Can you show the [minimal code that shows the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and include any error message yuoget?

Comment: If I import firebase from firebase It will say module not found. But if i give firrebase/auth it will work fine. Also my import cost extesion detects /auth,/app. But it does not detect Firebase from firebase
@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Can you share the file where you are trying to initialize Firebase and which version of Firebase have you installed?  Firebase recently released new Modular SDK v9+ so if the tutorial is older than that, same code might not work.

Comment: Are you assuming that `import Firebase` imports your firebase *data*? I just want clarification you are asking about adding Firebase to your development environment instead of accessing the actual data.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I am using V9 and the tutorial is using V8.Firebase made a video saying do not import the whole file just import useful ones. Did Firebase remove that functionality?

Comment: You can change the imports to compat like `import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"` to keep using V8 but those compat libs will be removed in future update. So I'd recommend checking out the documentation and following the new V9 SDK.